# Interpretation of the chiral anomaly a-la Alvarez-Gaume

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-anomalies, 1pi-effective-action, functional-determinants

In the paper "The topological meaning of non-abelian anomalies" written by Alvares-Gaume and Ginsparg they argue the appearing of the (gauge) anomaly in a theory with chiral fermions in the following way.

Suppose the (euclidean) action of massless Dirac fermion interacting with the gauge field:
$$
S = \int d^{4}x\bar{\psi}i(\partial + AP_{L})\psi , \quad \partial \equiv \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}, \quad A \equiv A_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}, \quad P_{L} \equiv \frac{1 - \gamma_{5}}{2}
$$ 
Let's integrate out the fermions and obtain the one-loop quantum effective action $\Gamma[A]$:
$$
e^{-\Gamma[A]} = \int d\bar{\psi}d\psi e^{-S[\bar{\psi},\psi]}
$$
Formally we can write
$$
\Gamma[A] = \text{ln}\big(\text{det}(iD) \big), \ \ \text{where } D = \partial + AP_{L}
$$
is the **Dirac operator**.

This action is expected to be gauge-variant since the operator $iD$ isn't gauge-invariant:
$$
A \to A^{g} = g^{-1}(A + \partial )g \Rightarrow iD[A] \to iD[A^{g}] \neq g^{-1}iDg
$$
Finally, it can be then shown that the gauge-variant part of the effective action - the gauge anomaly - is contained in the phase of $\text{det}(iD)$.

Aside from chiral gauge anomalies we also have the chiral axial anomalies, which are connected with the breaking of the global axial symmetry. They have the same properties as the gauge anomalies. However, I can't construct a clear explanation of its existence based on the properties of the Dirac operator in the spirit of the one given above, without tedious derivation a-la Fujikawa.

This is because it seems that no such meaning as the axial symmetry exist when we integrate over fermions in the theory with the Dirac operator
$$
D = \gamma_{\mu}(i\partial^{\mu} + V^{\mu})
$$ 
Therefore I can't think about the anomalous axial symmetry in the spirit of idea given above. However, I can introduce the external axial vector $A_{\mu}$ with the coupling $\gamma_{5}A_{\mu}$, then to define the anomaly, and then to set the external field $A_{\mu}$ to zero. Is this way correct?

If no, does exist an argument of relation of the axial anomaly to properties of the Dirac operator similar to represented above?